# Seasonal ARIMA Modelling in R

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, forecasting, arima

I have monthly price data for a commodity from 2007 to 2017. You can find it in the following link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxRCOgKAL4itcUZlOExrUmVOanc
I need to forecast it using Seasonal ARIMA model in R for next year. When I am using `auto.arima` function, it suggests me the best model as `ARIMA(0,1,1)` instead of `ARIMA(p,d,q)(P,D,Q)12`. The seasonal part of the `model(P,D,Q)` is somehow missing. I do not know why is this happening. Is my data not seasonal or is there something wrong in my code. Also the forecast value given by the model is constant for the next months which is insignificant. Please help! 
Here is the code:

```
data <- read.delim("C:/Users/hp/Desktop/heckyl/forecasting model/Soybean_Prices.txt", header=F)
View(data)
summary(data)
summary(data)
ts.data = ts(data, frequency=12, start=c(2007,6))
ts.data
plot(ts.data)

dim(as.matrix(ts.data))
################################################################################

# Training and Testing Dataset
data.train = window(ts.data, start = c(2007,6), end = c(2013,12)) 
plot(data.train)
dim(as.matrix(data.train))
data.test = window(ts.data, start = c(2014,1))
plot(data.test)
dim(as.matrix(data.test))
################################################################################

# Developing an SARIMA model and Analysis of Model
library(forecast)
arima1 = auto.arima(data.train, trace=FALSE, test="kpss",  ic="aic")
summary(arima1)
confint(arima1)

# Residual Diagonostics
plot.ts(arima1$residuals)
Box.test(arima1$residuals,lag=20, type="Ljung-Box")
acf(arima1$residuals, lag.max=24, main="ACF of the Model")
Box.test(arima1$residuals^2,lag=20, type="Ljung-Box")
library(tseries)
jarque.bera.test(arima1$residuals)

arima1.forecast= forecast.Arima(arima1, h=41)
arima1.forecast
plot(arima1.forecast, xlab="Years", ylab="Price for Soybean")

library(TSPred)
plotarimapred(data.test, arima1, xlim=c(2014, 2017), range.percent = 0.05)
accuracy(arima1.forecast, data.test)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "force" seasonality by setting D=1 or adding regressors. If you think there is more complex seasonality you may consider using Fourier terms? See this link [complex seasonality Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/complexseasonality.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command rather the one you are using for getting the parameters of ARIMA.

```
arima1 = auto.arima(data.train, trace=FALSE, test="kpss", ic="aic", 
                    stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE)
```

Sometimes using these commands gives the best model.

Comment: [stats.SE] isn't supposed to be a code help site.  We're a *statistics* Q & A site. Can you explain this code & why it helps find the best model?

Answer (score 0):

your data suggests the following model[image]

with [image] . The actual , fit and forecast is here [image] . The data suggests a level shift (visually obvious) and two statically significant seasonal indicators (April and September )and a few anomalies (6). I used R to do the analysis. Unfortunately auto.arima makes some critical assumptions about model form i.e. no level shifts and no seasonal pulses/indicators and of course no anomalies . It is always good to read the fine print.

The fact that there are only two months of the year that exhibit "seasonality" goes to explain why auto.arima delivered a model that had a "seasonal component somehow missing". Even a broken clock is right twice a day and in this case the clock was "nearly right" insofar as that there is no substantive auto-projective seasonal component/effect just a deterministic component/effect for the months of April and September.

6 period out forecast ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you please share the R code for my reference?
 Also, your model also shows constant forecast values, why is that so? In actual, agricultural commodity prices fluctuate a lot.

Comment: I used AUTOBOX which is available in R. The fact that the expected value is the same save for the two months of the year just means there is no permanent growth expected. I added a 6 period forecast just to illustrate tat the forecasts (short-term) are not constant. The confidence bands suggest (as expected) increasing uncertainty as you go forward.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can force the function auto.arima() to return the seasonal model by using like this

```
auto.arima(database,seasonal=T)
```