# Custom metric for model selection in auto.arima

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I'm using the `auto.arima` function of the`forecast` package. I would like to perform the model selection using a custom metric instead of the usual information criteria. Is there a way to do that in `auto.arima` or I have to create my own solution in another way?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281646/seasonal-arima-modelling-in-r/287789#287789 comments on some of the critical assumptions which limit the actal model selection. What metric are you considering and why ?

Comment: I have added experimental support for this in `fable::ARIMA()` via the `selection_metric` argument: https://github.com/tidyverts/fable/issues/280
It accepts a function which computes a metric from the `stats::arima()` output object, which is minimised to give the best model.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this in `auto.arima()`. You will need to replicate the code and change the information criteria to whatever metric you want to use.

(The same holds for the `ARIMA()` function in the successor [`fable`](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/fable/index.html) package.)